# Условие остановки цикла

Tags: c, циклы, c++

Не могу до конца понять, как правильно ставить условие в while цикле, чтобы оно останавливалось.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float rashod, total = 0, poln_rashod = 0;
    int km, i;

    while (rashod == -1) {
        printf("Input rashod - ");
        scanf("%f", &rashod);
        printf("Input km - ");
        scanf("%d", &km);

        ++i;

        poln_rashod = km / rashod;
        printf("for that zapravki - %fn", poln_rashod);

        total += poln_rashod;
    }
    total = poln_rashod / i;
    printf("srednee chislo - %f", total);
}
```

Comment: А когда оно должно останавливаться?

Comment: Меня терзают смутные подозрения, что этот цикл и не начнется.

Comment: Должно остановиться после ввода "-1"

Comment: А теперь подумайте, какое значение будет иметь переменная rashod перед началом цикла )))

Comment: Да не начнется, проблема в том что при условии, что (rashod <= -1) программу нельзя остановить, она просто зациклена, и я не могу понять как сделать, чтобы она выходила из цикла и дальше передавала управление операторам.

Comment: Ваш rashod может иметь любое значение потому что не инициализирован.
А в большинстве случаев там хранится мусор вроде -85901 и.т.д
Поэтому при условии что условие
 (-85901 <= -1) 
начинается вечный цикл.

While следует читать так:

пока выражение между круглых скобок возвращает true или 1 выполнять то что в фигурных скобках.
while(rashod == -1)
{
}

Во первых инициализируйте 

float rashod = -1;
int i=0;

Во вторых выходить из цикла можно оператором break;

Comment: А что за переменная такая "рашод"? Кстати где-то я слыхал такое что переменные с плавающей запятой лучше в циклах не использовать, то ли из-за ошибок в округлении то ли еще чего-то

Comment: Ну в некоторых языках для float нет операций "равно" и "неравно"

Хотя, возможно, я что-то и напутал. Поскольку не могу вспомнить, где же я такое видел.

Comment: Действительно, операции сравнения в случае переменных с плавающей запятой - дело довольно опасное. Особенно, если это результат каких-то арифметических действий. Использовать или нет - надо смотреть по контексту.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat 
Для базовых типов перегрузка невозможна.


Я помню в библиотеке для работы с большими числами, была ошибка для дробей.
При определенной ситуации переменная должна быть равна 5. Однако библиотека записывает это примерно так 5.000000000000000000001.
Из-за этого я долго пытался найти, что приводит к ошибке.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat И откуда такие сведения? Совет: подучить русский язык, затем C++

Comment: @manking Трудно найти отсутствующую чёрную кошку в тёмной комнате? (В смысле -- ошибки там и не было. "Это не баг -- это фича")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так

```
while (1) {
    printf("Input rashod - ");
    scanf("%f", &rashod);
    if (rashod < 0) break;
```

И далее по тексту. Хотя, проверьте общий алгоритм. Что-то в нем не в порядке.

**Added.** Если нельзя использовать break, то можно так

```
bool flag=true;
while (flag) {
    printf("Input rashod - ");
    scanf("%f", &rashod);
    if (rashod < 0) {
        flag=false;
    }
    else {
    //Выполняем остальной код

    }
}
```

Comment: Я забыл написать, что в задаче можно пользоваться "while, if-else" и больше никакими управляющими конструкциями.
Проблема в том, что программирую только 3 день, и не работал никогда с такими ресурсами как этот, так что скорее всего постановку вопроса изначально неправильно задаю.

Comment: А где здесь еще другие управляющие конструкции?

Answer (score 0):

без break

```
float rashod = 1.0, ...

while (rashod > 0){ ...
```

Comment: Тут весь прикол в том, что проверка значения этой переменной должна происходить в середине итерации. И далее цикл либо продолжается, либо прерывается.

Comment: тогда break лутший выход

Comment: Ясно дело.

Answer (score -1):

Ты пошел в правильном направлении, правда с логикой напутал. While выполняется пока условие истинно, а оно у тебя с самого начала ложно.
Должно быть так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float rashod, total = 0, poln_rashod = 0;
    int km, i;

    while (rashod != -1) {
        printf("Input rashod - ");
        scanf("%f", &rashod);
        printf("Input km - ");
        scanf("%d", &km);

        ++i;

        poln_rashod = km / rashod;
        printf("for that zapravki - %fn", poln_rashod);

        total += poln_rashod;
    }
    total = poln_rashod / i;
    printf("srednee chislo - %f", total);
}
```

Comment: Хотя я не вижу где ты i присваиваешь значение, хотя потом ты на него делишь полный расход!